# Is there any params for setting 'Application Priority'?

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn, hive-configuration

I am looking for a way to set application priority for task in hive. When task is committed, I want to set a high priority (like 100) to it. this param can be seen on page: [image]
I am looking for a param like 'set mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096;',so I can set priority for this task.

Answer (score 2):

In hive session, also it is possible to set the same property in [map-reduce program configuration](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/17151/priority-of-a-hadoop-job.html):

```
SET mapreduce.job.priority=VERY_HIGH;
```

For the job_id:

```
 hadoop job -set-priority <job-id> <priority>
```

There are five possible priority levels:

```
VERY_HIGH
HIGH
NORMAL
LOW
VERY_LOW
```

Queue priority configuration: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html#Setup_for_application_priority.

Comment: Is it possible to change the priority after the job was submitted by doing `hadoop job -set-priority <job-id> <priority> `?

Comment: @MemphisMeng Yes, it works for already running jobs